# Using COUNT CASE WHEN MONTH Statement in MariaDB 10.2.15

Tags: sql, mariadb

I created a query to calculate the Amount of Id in a **table** using `COUNT`, `CASE`, `WHEN` and `MONTH` ..

Code:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 1 THEN LogsFormatted.Id ELSE 0 END ) AS '1',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 2 THEN LogsFormatted.Id ELSE 0 END ) AS '2'
FROM
    HrAttLogsFormatted AS LogsFormatted
WHERE
    LogsFormatted.DateIn BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-31'
    AND LogsFormatted.Late != ''
```

**Output :**

```
| 1    | 2    |
| 1378 | 1378 |
```

The output I want to make is to *calculate* the Id in each *month*, namely Month 1 and Month 2

```
| 1    | 2    |
| 792  | 586  |
```

**The data above is a fact**

Using the above query instead adds up between the results of calculating month 1 and month 2

Comment: Would using `sum` instead of `count` help?

Comment: @shahkalpeshIn this case I want to count the number of records in the database with a number of conditions

Comment: I understand. Did you try using `sum`? Does it help?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Yes, I've tried using sum but can't count the number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be counting `NULL` when the criteria in your `CASE` expression does not match.  Also, I prefer counting `1` unless you really want to the count the Ids themselves.  This version should work:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS '1',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS '2'
FROM HrAttLogsFormatted AS lf
WHERE
    lf.DateIn BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-31' AND
    lf.Late != '';
```

Note carefully that the current counts you are seeing sum up to the individual counts, that is:

```
1378 = 792 + 586
```

The reason for this is the the `COUNT` function "counts" any non `NULL` value as 1, and any `NULL` value as zero.  Your current `CASE` expression will *always* count 1, for *every* record in the table.

Comment: Thanks, it's work and I understand the understanding of the concepts described

Comment: More tersely:  `SUM(MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 1) AS '1'`

Answer (score 1):

remove else part from case when expression - if you use else with 0 then count takes that also in consideration which gives u actually wrong ouput

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 1 THEN LogsFormatted.Id END ) AS '1',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 2 THEN LogsFormatted.Id  END ) AS '2'
FROM
    HrAttLogsFormatted AS LogsFormatted
WHERE
    LogsFormatted.DateIn BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-31'
    AND LogsFormatted.Late != ''
```

Comment: Yes, I don't consider 0 in the sql function ... Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB, I would just use `SUM()` with a boolean:

```
SELECT SUM( MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 1 ) as month_1,
       SUM( MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 2 ) as month_2
FROM HrAttLogsFormatted lf
WHERE lf.DateIn >= '2019-01-01' AND 
      lf.DateIn < '2020-01-01' AND
      lf.Late <> '';
```

This assumes that the id that you are counting is never `NULL` (a reasonable assumption for an id).

Note other changes:

- The column aliases do not need to be escaped.  Don't use non-standard names, unless you need them -- for some reason -- for downstream processing.
- This uses a shorter table alias, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- The date comparisons use inequalities, so this works both for `date`s and `datetime`s.
- `<>` is the standard SQL comparison operator for inequality.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't think of using sum ... Thank you for the experience